# Find div class, which contain word

Tags: php, html

I would like to find div with class name, but I don't have whole class name. For example:

```
<div class="article_main">
Article
</div>
```

Code to find div:

```
$html = file_get_contents($_POST['url']);
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = '';
foreach($xpath->evaluate('//div[@class="article"]/node()') as $childNode) {
  $result .= $dom->saveHtml($childNode);
}
```

I would like to find div, which class contains word "article". Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `contains` in the XPath:

```
$xpath->evaluate('//div[contains(@class, "article")]/node()')
```

Test:

```
<?php
$html = '<div class="article_main">Article</div>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = '';
foreach($xpath->evaluate('//div[contains(@class, "article")]/node()') as $childNode) {
  $result .= $dom->saveHtml($childNode);
}
echo $result;
```

Output:

```
Article
```

Comment: You got in 3 minutes before me, and probably what he was after, as well!

Answer (score 0):

Does this **have** to be done server-side? If no, then you can do it with jQuery, and it is simply either:

```
var results = $(div).filter(function(){ return $(this).hasClass('whatever'); /* whatever is class name here */ });
```

or

```
var results = $(div).filter(function(){ return $(this).text().indexOf("text to search for") !== -1 });
```

For server-side handling, simply use AJAX to send it to your PHP code